# Do we have $\log\Gamma(2x+1)-2\log\Gamma(x+1)\ge\log(x^2+1)$ for $x\in[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, gamma-function, digamma-function

> Prove or disprove that, for all $x \in [0, 1]$,
> $$\log\Gamma(2x+1)-2\log\Gamma(x+1)\ge\log(x^2+1).$$
> Here $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.

I discovered this relation by accidentally drawing the graph of the two functions. Here is the image.

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |

Given that the two functions intersect at both $x=0$ and $x=1$, is there any easy way to prove the inequality?

Comment: Unless my algebra had a typo this is equivalent to $2\Gamma(2)\geq\Gamma()^2(^2+1)$ which appears to be valid for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @pshmath0 Yes, once the inequality is proved for $x\in[0,1]$, it can be easily extended to $x\in\left[-\dfrac{1}{2},+\infty\right)$ by recursion.

Comment: Using Legendre's duplication formula we have
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(x+1/2)2^{2x}\pi^{-1/2}\geq\Gamma(x)^2x(x^2+1),$$
so dividing by $\Gamma(x)$,
$$\Gamma(x+1/2)2^{2x}\geq\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(x)x(x^2+1).$$ From here you may be able to use a series representation of $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

We use the integral representation of $\ln\Gamma(y+1)$:
$$\ln\Gamma(y+1) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\left(y\mathrm{e}^{-t} + \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t(y+1)} - \mathrm{e}^{-t}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t. \tag{1}$$
(See: https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/LogGamma/07/01/01/.)

Using (1), we have
$$\ln \Gamma(2x + 1)
= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\left(2x\mathrm{e}^{-t} + \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t(2x+1)} - \mathrm{e}^{-t}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t, \tag{2}$$
and
$$\ln\Gamma(x+1)
= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\left(x\mathrm{e}^{-t} + \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t(x+1)} - \mathrm{e}^{-t}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t. \tag{3}$$

Using the known identity (for $u > 0$)
$$\ln u = \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t} - \mathrm{e}^{-ut}}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t,$$
we have
$$\ln(x^2 + 1) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t} - \mathrm{e}^{-(x^2 + 1)t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t. \tag{4}$$

Using (2), (3) and (4), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\ln \Gamma(2x+1)-2\ln\Gamma(x+1) -  \ln(x^2+1)\\[6pt]
 ={}&
 \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t} + \mathrm{e}^{-2tx} - 2\mathrm{e}^{-tx} + \mathrm{e}^{-tx^2} - \mathrm{e}^{-t(x^2 + 1)}}{t(\mathrm{e}^t - 1)}\,\mathrm{d} t. \tag{5}
\end{align*}

From (5), it suffices to prove that, for all $t \ge 0$ and $x\in [0, 1]$,
$$\mathrm{e}^{-t} + \mathrm{e}^{-2tx} - 2\mathrm{e}^{-tx} + \mathrm{e}^{-tx^2} - \mathrm{e}^{-t(x^2 + 1)} \ge 0. \tag{6}$$

We have
$$\mathrm{e}^{-tx^2} - \mathrm{e}^{-t(x^2 + 1)}
= \mathrm{e}^{tx(1 - x)}\mathrm{e}^{-tx}(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t})
\ge [1 + tx(1 - x)]\mathrm{e}^{-tx}(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t}) \tag{7}$$
where we use $\mathrm{e}^{u} \ge 1 + u$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$.

From (6) and (7), it suffices to prove that
$$\mathrm{e}^{-t} + \mathrm{e}^{-2tx} - 2\mathrm{e}^{-tx}
+ [1 + tx(1 - x)]\mathrm{e}^{-tx}(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t}) \ge 0$$
or (multiplying both sides by $\mathrm{e}^{tx}$)
$$\mathrm{e}^{-t(1 - x)} + \mathrm{e}^{-tx} - 2 + [1 + tx(1 - x)](1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t}) \ge 0. \tag{8}$$

Clearly, we only need to prove the case that $x\in [0, 1/2]$.

Let
$$f(x) := \mathrm{e}^{-t(1 - x)} + \mathrm{e}^{-tx} - 2 + [1 + tx(1 - x)](1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t}).$$
We have
$$f'(x) = t\mathrm{e}^{-t(1 - x)} - t\mathrm{e}^{-tx} + t(1 - 2x)(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t})$$
and
$$f'''(x) = t^3(\mathrm{e}^{-t(1 - x)} - \mathrm{e}^{-tx}) \le 0.$$
Thus, $f'(x)$ is concave on $[0, 1/2]$.
Also, we have $f'(0) = f'(1/2) = 0$.
Thus, we have $f'(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1/2]$. Also, $f(0) = 0$. Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1/2]$.

We are done.

Comment: That's very kind of you. Thanks!

Comment: @JianingSong You are welcome.